# Share machine key between two web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, oauth

I have two questions related with using of machine key IIS.

1. I've generated machine key using IIS and applied it to both my web applications. The first web application (oauth provider) grants access token and I want to apply granted access token to second web application (service provider). If I generate machine key and apply it to both web application should service provider accept access token issued by oauth provider (oauth provider and resource provider are hosted on the same IIS as different web application)? 
   I have an issue with authorization on service provider using access token.

Maybe I have issue with Windows Registry?

2. If I generate machine keys on remote IIS, can I use it for my web applications that are run from IIS Express on my local machine?